# How to get my private key?

Tags: ethereumjs

I want to use the ecSign-function in the ethereumjs-util-library. But that needs a private key. So how and where do i get my private key for my wallet?

Comment: What wallet or node software are you running?

Comment: I use the Mist-Browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use https://www.myetherwallet.com/... Include the wallet File and copy and paste the Private key

Comment: Thats what i actually did and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I tried to do this and got the error `RangeError: private key length is invalid`